# Rails3: How do I set variables for the app depending on the ENVIRONMENT

Tags: ruby-on-rails

If my app has to behave differently according to the ENV state: production, testing or development, how do I set those variables?

For example, if I am in production i want the variable @subdomains = 2 and if I am in development then @subdomains = 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set these in *config/environments/production.rb* and *config/environments/development.rb* and then if you're running a server, restart it for the changes to these files to take effect.

Comment: SUBDOMAINS=1 if you want to set a global

Comment: I get uninitialized constant ApplicationHelper::NUMBER_OF_SUBDOMAINS       I have the NUMBER_OF_SUBDOMAINS = 1   inside de configure in each environment

Comment: @Nerian: you have to restart your server for the changes to be detected to these files.